# Writing to a shared resource from 2 different threads without using sync mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I have the following code (written in c#, but can easily be translated to your prefered language...)

```
class Program
{
    static int sharedState = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(UpdateState);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(UpdateState);
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("sharedState value is {0}.", sharedState);
    }

    static void UpdateState()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            sharedState++;
    }
}
```

As you anyone can guess, this code creates two workers threads that increment the shared state value by one for 10 time. The code does not have any synchronization mechanism (such as mutex, monitor or any other...) while accessing and writing the shared value 'sharedState', and the main thread is waiting for the two workers to finish their job (Join).
Does some one can please explain to me what is the problem with this code, and is it possible that at the end - the value of 'sharedState' will be 2? (a friend of mine was asked this question, and they told him that it is possible, and we both cant understand how...)
BTW - when I run this code I get 20 every time...

Answer (score 3):

The threads don't live long enough.  The odds that they'll run concurrently are small with such a short loop, especially on a multicore machine.  By the time you start the 2nd thread, the 1st thread is already done.  Since it takes but a fraction of a microsecond, much less than what it takes to get a thread started. Let them loop for at least ten million times to increase the odds and see the race. Output on my machine in the Release build:

> sharedState value is 13952221.

With different values each time I run it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not thread safe because

```
sharedState++;
```

is interpreted internally like:

- Push the value from static property to evaluation stack
- Increament the value in evaluation stack
- Replace the value in static property with value from evaluation stack

Now if this operation is not atomic / synchronized you can have more threads taking the value from the static property concurrently but only modification from the last thread will be stored.

If you want thread safe increment you should use `Interlocked.Increment`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem, indeed. But it will only accour if you run the loop very very often:

assume the state is 1
thread a reads the state and gets 1
thread a is paused by the os and b is run
thread b reads the state and gets 1
thread b calculates 1+1 and writes 2
thread b reads 2
thread b calculates 2+1 and writes 3
...
thread a calculates 1+1 and writes 2
3 increments where executed and the state has changed from 1 to 2

But you will never ever get a result beeing lower than your lowest boundary condition. So if you start with 0 and each thread increments 10 times you will always get 10 or higher, no matter what happends.

For snychronisation:
Interlocked.Increment(ref whatever) is your friend. It is implemented using the lock-prefix in assembler. It is the most efficient way to safely increment a value.
Slightly more complex operations can be performed using CompareEcxchange. But lock(somthing) is very efficient, too.

Comment: According to your answer, thread a did not finish the loop, it has 7 more iterations so the value of 'sharedState' will be more than 2. Or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

1. Both threads read the variable, and get the value 0.
2. Thread 1 manages to increment the variable 9 times.
3. Thread 2 manages to increment the variable once. But it thought it was 0 before, so its new value is 1.
4. Both threads read the variable, and get the value 1.
5. Thread 2 manages to increment the variable 9 times.
6. Thread 1 manages to increment the variable once. But it thought it was 1 before, so its new value is 2.

Of course, this is extremely unlikely in practice!